# How to allow the right people to access this function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions, logic

Basically every user has a group of permissions based on their role (Administrator, manager, seller etc) and they all have an option to edit their profile, but I want the Administrator to be able to edit everyone's profiles.

The edit function looks something like this (I'm using Codeigniter)

```
function edit($id)
{
 if(!in_array('editUser'))
 {
   redirect('home');
 }
 //rest of the code...
}
```

The first thought was to check if the session id of the user trying to edit the page was the same as the id of the user being edited but that would render the administrator's ability to edit everyone's profiles useless.

Hope I can get an answer today, thank you for the help.

**EDIT**

I fixed this by adding another condition and reversing them:

```php
function edit($id)
{
 if(in_array('editUser', $perms) || $this->session->userdata('id') == $id)
 {
  //rest of the code...
 }else{
  redirect('home');
 }
}
```

Comment: I could also just add a whole new function that would do the same thing but would be designated for 2 different roles (administrator and all the other roles) but I'm not a fan of that idea

Comment: you could write a function which checks if the id of the user trying to edit the page was the same as the id of the user being edited, OR if the ID of the current user is in the administrator's role.

Comment: I tried doing
if(!in_array('editUser', $perms) || $this->session->userdata('id') != $id)
but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Store the Role in Session when login the user and handle it

For example

```
    if($this->session->userdata('role') == 'admin'){
      // Show admin folder files 
    }elseif($this->session->userdata('role') == 'normal_user'){
    // Other user folder files 
   }
```

There is lot of role based libraries available in google for Codeigniter
[Commonly used library link](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding another condition and reversing them:

```php
function edit($id)
{
 if(in_array('editUser', $perms) || $this->session->userdata('id') == $id)
 {
  //rest of the code...
 }else{
  redirect('home');
 }
}
```

Sorry for the dumb question but it's been bugging me for a while and I finally got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

you can control by both **controller** as well as **view** page

by this method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634187/7817622